# React component throwing TypeScript error for function passed in as prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a Class based React Component that accepts a function as a prop.

The component was originally a stateless functional component that accepted the same function without any TypeScript errors.

Now that I've converted it to a class component I'm getting an error when I call the function: `Property 'onRouteChange' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{}> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'`

As well as an error when I de-structure it in the props: `Property 'onRouteChange' is missing in type 'Readonly<{}> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>' but required in type '{ onRouteChange: any; }'.`

I initially tried to define it in the types declaration at the top of the file but that's not working either.

`Component`

```
type SignInState = {
  signInEmail: string,
  signInPassword: string
}

class SignIn extends Component<{}, SignInState> {
  constructor(props: {}){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      signInEmail: '',
      signInPassword: ''
    }
  }

  onEmailChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
      this.setState({ signInEmail: e.target.value })
  }

  onPasswordChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    this.setState({ signInPassword: e.target.value })
  }

  onSubmitSignIn = () => {
    // fetch()
    console.log(this.state);
// TS Error: Property 'onRouteChange' does not exist
    this.props.onRouteChange('home');
  }
  
  render() {
// TS Error: Property 'onRouteChange' is missing in type 'Readonly<{}> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>' 
    const { onRouteChange } : { onRouteChange: any} = this.props

    return (
      <Container>
        <Main>
          <Form>
            <Fieldset>
              <SignInTitle>Sign In</SignInTitle>
              <EmailAddressSection>
                <Label>Email</Label>
                <EmailInput />
              </EmailAddressSection>
              <PasswordSection>
                <Label>Password</Label>
                <PasswordInput />
              </PasswordSection>
            </Fieldset>
            <div>
              <SignInButton
                onClick={this.onSubmitSignIn}
                type="submit"
                value="Sign in"
              />
            </div>
            <AccountOptionsSection>
              <AccountOption onClick={() => onRouteChange("register")}>
                Register
              </AccountOption>
            </AccountOptionsSection>
          </Form>
        </Main>
      </Container>
    );
  }
};

export default SignIn;
```

Comment: Your props are typed to an empty object `Component<{}, SignInState>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class SignIn extends Component<{}, SignInState>
```

The first param to Component type is props type , and you have not defined it, therefore the error.

Define a interface,

```
interface ISignInProp {

onRouteChange:any
}
```

and pass it to your Component

```
class SignIn extends Component<ISignInProp , SignInState>
```

Comment: That did it! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Create a `type` or an `interface` for your props just as you did with your state.

**Props Interface**

```js
// interface over type literal
interface IProps { 
 onRouteChange: (param: string) => void
}
```

**Avoid Typing to `any`**

Try to avoid typing something to `any`. You are basically telling typescript this has no type. That defeats the purpose of TS. If you truly do not know, type it to `unknown`.

But, you are passing a `string` home so you have some information on it that you can use to type it a little better.

Here, I am guessing `onRouteChange` is a function that accepts one parameter of type string and returns nothing (does a side effect). You can update this accordingly.

**Typing Your Component Props**

You do exactly what you did with your state type (prefer interface over types).

```js
class SignIn extends Component<IProps, IState>
```

Now you should not have to type `onRouteChange` when you destructure it.

```js
const { onRouteChange } : { onRouteChange: any} = this.props
```

becomes

```js
const { onRouteChange } = this.props
```